# how do I get functionality like javap in kotlin?

Tags: class, kotlin

Whenever we type `javap java.lang.Number` in the command line. The command outputs all the associated members of the class. This is a very helpful to determine all the members of a class and for further research on various methods, constructors etc. But, I don't know a way how to achieve this thing in kotlin class. Can anyone tell me how inspect classes in Kotlin

Comment: When targeting the JVM the Kotlin source is compiled to byte-code same as Java. You can use `javap` on those class files in that case.

Comment: How do I inspect kotlin.collections.List ? This is just an example

Comment: I'm not sure about `kotlin.collections.List`. I've really only used `javap` on Kotlin code I've compiled. But if you have the standard library JAR (and/or other Kotlin-related JARs) then you should be able to `-cp` to it and inspect a specified class. For instance, using `javap -cp ...\kotlin-stdlib.jar kotlin.collections.EmptyList` worked for me. But it doesn't seem like `kotlin.collections.List` actually exists in compiled form (or maybe I'm just missing it).